# Android how to call another Image after 3 times click on same Image?

Tags: android, view, android-imageview, android-image, onclicklistener

I am developing application on Images.

In that if I click on same image the image will replace by another one that already into my **Drawable**

Right now onclick I am able to display only Toast Message; but I want to replace Image. I don't know How to do?
Any Help and suggestion  appreciable.

you can take it images name as : img1 ,img2 ,img3.

```
   ImageView imgV = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imgV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (v.isClickable()) {
                            i++;
                            String ii = new Integer(i).toString();
                            Log.i("Inside", ii);
                            if (ii.equals("3")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call another Image ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
```

Comment: Same as Toast message, try it to set different image. If failed then let us know.

Comment: keep trust in you :) Self confidence matters....Anyway cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView imgV = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.img1);
imgV.setClickable(true);
int counter = 0;

imgV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    i++;
    if(i == 3){
    imgV.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    //Or you may want to use
    //imgV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);

    i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ..Its work for me.
I have one question instead of images if there is layout(main2.xml).
shall I go for this >
right now I am using call another class everytime for display another layout .
will it possible to replace like this?

Comment: Ohh good. If this woks for you, you can mark it as accepted. And ofr replacing the layout you can make use of [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).